# Make a unchecked HTML checkbox submit a checked value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a Zoho CRM web to lead form and I need to include an Email Opt Out.

By using the following field, if the checkbox is checked, the user is unsubscribed in the Zoho CRM.

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="Email Opt Out" />
```

However, I need to reverse this, so that the field to unsubscribe the user if the checkbox is unchecked, but not submit anything/unsubscribe the user is the box is checked.

Essentially I need the checkbox to work the other way round: a checked value is submitted if the checkbox is unchecked, and and unchecked value submitted if it is checked.

I have tried the following, but it doesnt work:
** Note - I would like the checkbox to be checked by default.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="Email Opt Out" value="TRUE"/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Email Opt Out" checked="checked" value="FALSE"/>
```

Comment: Can't you invert the output in your backend?
Or in general: what stops you from changing your text so that the textbox can work as it does :P

Comment: Agree with Marv. Easiest solution seems to reverse the boolean wherever you process the form input (assumably the action page).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. 1. Unable to adjust backend as it's a 3rd party system (Zoho) 2. that would be the easy solution, but unfortunately not feasible in this situation.

Comment: Could you use javascript or jQuery to edit the value before sending? I'm asking since you didn't tag it with any of these.

Comment: Niklas, I'm not sure if JS/jQuery would work, as resumably the solution I tried with the hidden field would have worked?

Comment: @Sha What he means is have a submit event handler that checks if the box is checked or not, and then adds the key/value pair to the payload before sending to the action url.

Comment: Marv has the right solution, on your back end simply check if the checkbox has been checked and prevent instead of going through with

Comment: One question I have is where is this form at? If it's on an email, jquery is out of the question.

Comment: It's on an HTML website. Would it be worth inverting the checkbox onsubmit of the form?

Comment: Use radio buttons or a select element instead. They are designed for sending one out of a collection of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert the value with jQuery/JS:

https://jsfiddle.net/09noubr9/

```js
$('input[name="boolValue"]').on('change', function() {
  $('input[name="invertBoolValue"]').val(!$(this).is(':checked'))
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="boolValue" />
<input type="hidden" name="invertBoolValue" />
```